# React filtering action not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Given a currentUser with an id, and a database of 'events' created by various users, I am trying to fetch a filtered list of events that include only events created by the current user, in other words, their events.

My plan of attack was to make a piece of the state a 'filter' which would be updated depending on various things, but right now I am having trouble even getting the most basic filter to work.

The error always occurs within the function immediately below this paragraph. I have gotten an error staying "currentUser" is undefined, or that "author_id" is undefined or "cannot read property author_id or undefined."

currentUser is defined on the store when I checked with getState.

```
filterMyEvents() {
    let cid = currentUser.id
    let e = this.props.events
    let myEventsFilter = (events, id) => {
      debugger
      (cid === e[id].author_id)
    }
    myEventsFilter = myEventsFilter.bind(null, this.props.events)
    this.props.updateFilter(myEventsFilter);
  }
```

The filtering takes place in Selector.js

```
export const allEventsByFilter = (events, filter) => {
if (filter) {
  return Object.keys(events).filter(filter);
} else {
  return events;
}
}
```

User Container:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.session.currentUser,
  requestEvents: requestEvents,
  events: allEventsByFilter(state.events, state.filter)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  requestEvents: () => { dispatch(requestEvents()) },
  updateFilter: (filter) => dispatch(updateFilter(filter))
})
```

Filter actions:

```
export const FilterConstants = {
  UPDATE_FILTER: "UPDATE_FILTER"
};

export const updateFilter = (filter) => ({
  type: FilterConstants.UPDATE_FILTER,
  filter
});
```

Filters reducer

```
const _defaultFilters = () => {
    return true;
}


const FiltersReducer = function(state = null, action){
  if (action.type === FilterConstants.UPDATE_FILTER){
    // const newFilter = {[action.filter]: action.value};
    return action.filter;
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Is `currentUser` passed into the component as a prop via state/store e.g. `this.props.currentUser`?

Comment: @char Yes, if you take a look at the user container above I pass it as a prop. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes I'm confirming if currentUser is passed along. I didn't want to assume but I wanted to assume (from what I can tell) you've connected the `currentUser` reducer to the component via mapStatetoProps and mapDispatchToProps.
What I was implicitly implying is that in the method `filterMyEvents`, try to access `currentUser` via `this.props.currentUser`, seeing that `currentUser` is a prop that is passed, not a global variable.

Comment: @char I think it helped. I can now get three event objects to render on the page(consistent with what is expected for that user), but they are all blank. What is getting lost?

Comment: if you are getting empty objects, it's probably means that you haven't dispatched an action to update the `currentUser` state.
Doing `currentUser: state.session.currentUser,` in the connect function doesn't set the state; it subscribes the component to the state.
Maybe try dispatching the an action to update the `currentUser` reducer with the `state.session.currentUser` on `componentWIllUpdate` method and see if that works.